# GET form method and submit button PHP

Tags: php, forms, get

I'm creating a form which will take a user ID from the input field using the `GET` variable and redirect to the next form page. I set form `"method="get"`, but after I click on the `Submit` button my URL looks like the following:

`http://example.com/neworder?uid=1234&submit...`

I would like to have `uid` only. Is there any way to submit button in `GET` method form which doesn't change the URL address?

Thanks guys!

Comment: if you don't want to change the url use POST

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `name` attribute from the submit button.

It serves no purpose, other then allowing it to be included in submitted form data (which you don't want), that isn't better serviced by the `id` attribute.